# iOS Core Data with iCloud import crash

Tags: ios, core-data, icloud

I am using Core Data and syncing it with iCloud, and I have started getting a crash while the persistent store is importing, and I have no idea how to solve it. Has anyone seen this before, or have any idea of how to catch the exception? The exception is not giving me any clues to the cause of this crash. I am thinking that it is an internal iCloud exception that I cannot catch, but I can't be sure. Here is the crash log:

```
Jul 28 11:42:20 MAP-iPhone-197e4 FOX Sports Listen[2197] <Warning>: -[_PFUbiquityRecordImportOperation main](721): CoreData: Ubiquity:  Error importing transaction log: <PFUbiquityTransactionLog: 0x190283a0>
    transactionLogLocation: <PFUbiquityLocation: 0x17e1da10>: /var/mobile/Library/Mobile Documents/24VQYD7JKT~com~foxsports~FOX-Sports-Listen/listen/mobile~04E0B687-9463-4BF4-88FF-7C2C3244949E/listen/tqO17ntQYATB3MNjHDY5lH3Y1iDbJcvGSr_8ZSZ9Puk=/D9CADD8D-2230-4547-AEDC-0CCAC6725AF5.1.cdt
    transactionNumber: 6
, exception: <PFUbiquityPeerRangeCache: 0x1928e9c0>
    localPeerID: listen
    storeName: mobile~72C62237-FE38-4B5C-8B60-557E41D79CA0

Unable to resolve global object IDs: (
    "<PFUbiquityGlobalObjectID: 0x1929cda0> (listen:FavoritedChannel:p9217:mobile~72C62237-FE38-4B5C-8B60-557E41D79CA0)"
)
{
    "mobile~04E0B687-9463-4BF4-88FF-7C2C3244949E" =     {
        FavoritedChannel =         {
            0 = "<PFUbiquitySQLCorePeerRange: 0x1928f850>\n\towningPeerID: mobile~04E0B687-9463-4BF4-88FF-7C2C3244949E\n\tentityName: FavoritedChannel\n\trangeStart: 6145\n\trangeEnd: 7168\n\tpeerStart: 0\n\tpeerEnd: 1023\n";
            6144 = "<PFUbiquitySQLCorePeerRange: 0x1928f9d0>\n\towningPeerID: mobile~04E0B687-9463-4BF4-88FF-7C2C3244949E\n\tentityName: FavoritedChannel\n\trangeStart: 8193\n\trangeEnd: 9216\n\tpeerStart: 6144\n\tpeerEnd: 7167\n";
            9216 = "<PFUbiquitySQLCorePeerRange: 0x1928f280>\n\towningPeerID: mobile~04E0B687-9463-4BF4-88FF-7C2C3244949E\n\tentityName: FavoritedChannel\n\trangeStart: 11265\n\trangeEnd: 12288\n\tpeerStart: 9216\n\tpeerEnd: 10239\n";
        };
    };
    "mobile~72C62237-FE38-4B5C-8B60-557E41D79CA0" =     {
        FavoritedChannel =         {
            8227 = "<PFUbiquitySQLCorePeerRange: 0x194ac020>\n\towningPeerID: mobile~72C62237-FE38-4B5C-8B60-557E41D79CA0\n\tentityName: FavoritedChannel\n\trangeStart: 12289\n\trangeEnd: 13312\n\tpeerStart: 8227\n\tpeerEnd: 9250\n";
            2085 = "<PFUbiquitySQLCorePeerRange: 0x1928f610>\n\towningPeerID: mobile~72C62237-FE38-4B5C-8B60-557E41D79CA0\n\tentityName: FavoritedChannel\n\trangeStart: 3073\n\trangeEnd: 4096\n\tpeerStart: 2085\n\tpeerEnd: 3108\n";
            5153 = "<PFUbiquitySQLCorePeerRange: 0x1928f910>\n\towningPeerID: mobile~72C62237-FE38-4B5C-8B60-557E41D79CA0\n\tentityName: FavoritedChannel\n\trangeStart: 7169\n\trangeEnd: 8192\n\tpeerStart: 5153\n\tpeerEnd: 6176\n";
            4097 = "<PFUbiquitySQLCorePeerRange: 0x1928f7a0>\n\towningPeerID: mobile~72C62237-FE38-4B5C-8B60-557E41D79CA0\n\tentityName: FavoritedChannel\n\trangeStart: 5121\n\trangeEnd: 6144\n\tpeerStart: 4097\n\tpeerEnd: 5120\n";
            1 = "<PFUbiquitySQLCorePeerRange: 0x1928f4a0>\n\towningPeerID: mobile~72C62237-FE38-4B5C-8B60-557E41D79CA0\n\tentityName: FavoritedChannel\n\trangeStart: 1025\n\trangeEnd: 2048\n\tpeerStart: 1\n\tpeerEnd: 1024\n";
            9217 = "<PFUbiquitySQLCorePeerRange: 0x19595cc0>\n\towningPeerID: mobile~72C62237-FE38-4B5C-8B60-557E41D79CA0\n\tentityName: FavoritedChannel\n\trangeStart: 17409\n\trangeEnd: 18432\n\tpeerStart: 9217\n\tpeerEnd: 10240\n";
        };
    };
    "mobile~CFE92744-142C-43D4-AAEC-FB647A06FCAD" =     {
        FavoritedChannel =         {
            0 = "<PFUbiquitySQLCorePeerRange: 0x1928f470>\n\towningPeerID: mobile~CFE92744-142C-43D4-AAEC-FB647A06FCAD\n\tentityName: FavoritedChannel\n\trangeStart: 1\n\trangeEnd: 1024\n\tpeerStart: 0\n\tpeerEnd: 1023\n";
            2048 = "<PFUbiquitySQLCorePeerRange: 0x1928f6d0>\n\towningPeerID: mobile~CFE92744-142C-43D4-AAEC-FB647A06FCAD\n\tentityName: FavoritedChannel\n\trangeStart: 4097\n\trangeEnd: 5120\n\tpeerStart: 2048\n\tpeerEnd: 3071\n";
            1024 = "<PFUbiquitySQLCorePeerRange: 0x1928f550>\n\towningPeerID: mobile~CFE92744-142C-43D4-AAEC-FB647A06FCAD\n\tentityName: FavoritedChannel\n\trangeStart: 2049\n\trangeEnd: 3072\n\tpeerStart: 1024\n\tpeerEnd: 2047\n";
            6144 = "<PFUbiquitySQLCorePeerRange: 0x1928fab0>\n\towningPeerID: mobile~CFE92744-142C-43D4-AAEC-FB647A06FCAD\n\tentityName: FavoritedChannel\n\trangeStart: 9217\n\trangeEnd: 10240\n\tpeerStart: 6144\n\tpeerEnd: 7167\n";
        };
    };
}
{
    FavoritedChannel =     (
        "<PFUbiquitySQLCorePeerRange: 0x1928f470>\n\towningPeerID: mobile~CFE92744-142C-43D4-AAEC-FB647A06FCAD\n\tentityName: FavoritedChannel\n\trangeStart: 1\n\trangeEnd: 1024\n\tpeerStart: 0\n\tpeerEnd: 1023\n",
        "<PFUbiquitySQLCorePeerRange: 0x1928f4a0>\n\towningPeerID: mobile~72C62237-FE38-4B5C-8B60-557E41D79CA0\n\tentityName: FavoritedChannel\n\trangeStart: 1025\n\trangeEnd: 2048\n\tpeerStart: 1\n\tpeerEnd: 1024\n",
        "<PFUbiquitySQLCorePeerRange: 0x1928f550>\n\towningPeerID: mobile~CFE92744-142C-43D4-AAEC-FB647A06FCAD\n\tentityName: FavoritedChannel\n\trangeStart: 2049\n\trangeEnd: 3072\n\tpeerStart: 1024\n\tpeerEnd: 2047\n",
        "<PFUbiquitySQLCorePeerRange: 0x1928f610>\n\towningPeerID: mobile~72C62237-FE38-4B5C-8B60-557E41D79CA0\n\tentityName: FavoritedChannel\n\trangeStart: 3073\n\trangeEnd: 4096\n\tpeerStart: 2085\n\tpeerEnd: 3108\n",
        "<PFUbiquitySQLCorePeerRange: 0x1928f6d0>\n\towningPeerID: mobile~CFE92744-142C-43D4-AAEC-FB647A06FCAD\n\tentityName: FavoritedChannel\n\trangeStart: 4097\n\trangeEnd: 5120\n\tpeerStart: 2048\n\tpeerEnd: 3071\n",
        "<PFUbiquitySQLCorePeerRange: 0x1928f7a0>\n\towningPeerID: mobile~72C62237-FE38-4B5C-8B60-557E41D79CA0\n\tentityName: FavoritedChannel\n\trangeStart: 5121\n\trangeEnd: 6144\n\tpeerStart: 4097\n\tpeerEnd: 5120\n",
        "<PFUbiquitySQLCorePeerRange: 0x1928f850>\n\towningPeerID: mobile~04E0B687-9463-4BF4-88FF-7C2C3244949E\n\tentityName: FavoritedChannel\n\trangeStart: 6145\n\trangeEnd: 7168\n\tpeerStart: 0\n\tpeerEnd: 1023\n",
        "<PFUbiquitySQLCorePeerRange: 0x1928f910>\n\towningPeerID: mobile~72C62237-FE38-4B5C-8B60-557E41D79CA0\n\tentityName: FavoritedChannel\n\trangeStart: 7169\n\trangeEnd: 8192\n\tpeerStart: 5153\n\tpeerEnd: 6176\n",
        "<PFUbiquitySQLCorePeerRange: 0x1928f9d0>\n\towningPeerID: mobile~04E0B687-9463-4BF4-88FF-7C2C3244949E\n\tentityName: FavoritedChannel\n\trangeStart: 8193\n\trangeEnd: 9216\n\tpeerStart: 6144\n\tpeerEnd: 7167\n",
        "<PFUbiquitySQLCorePeerRange: 0x1928fab0>\n\towningPeerID: mobile~CFE92744-142C-43D4-AAEC-FB647A06FCAD\n\tentityName: FavoritedChannel\n\trangeStart: 9217\n\trangeEnd: 10240\n\tpeerStart: 6144\n\tpeerEnd: 7167\n",
        "<PFUbiquitySQLCorePeerRange: 0x1928fb70>\n\towningPeerID: mobile~72C62237-FE38-4B5C-8B60-557E41D79CA0\n\tentityName: FavoritedChannel\n\trangeStart: 10241\n\trangeEnd: 11264\n\tpeerStart: 9217\n\tpeerEnd: 10240\n",
        "<PFUbiquitySQLCorePeerRange: 0x1928f280>\n\towningPeerID: mobile~04E0B687-9463-4BF4-88FF-7C2C3244949E\n\tentityName: FavoritedChannel\n\trangeStart: 11265\n\trangeEnd: 12288\n\tpeerStart: 9216\n\tpeerEnd: 10239\n",
        "<PFUbiquitySQLCorePeerRange: 0x194ac020>\n\towningPeerID: mobile~72C62237-FE38-4B5C-8B60-557E41D79CA0\n\tentityName: FavoritedChannel\n\trangeStart: 12289\n\trangeEnd: 13312\n\tpeerStart: 8227\n\tpeerEnd: 9250\n",
        "<PFUbiquitySQLCorePeerRange: 0x195934d0>\n\towningPeerID: mobile~72C62237-FE38-4B5C-8B60-557E41D79CA0\n\tentityName: FavoritedChannel\n\trangeStart: 13313\n\trangeEnd: 14336\n\tpeerStart: 9217\n\tpeerEnd: 10240\n",
        "<PFUbiquitySQLCorePeerRange: 0x1941f2e0>\n\towningPeerID: mobile~72C62237-FE38-4B5C-8B60-557E41D79CA0\n\tentityName: FavoritedChannel\n\trangeStart: 14337\n\trangeEnd: 15360\n\tpeerStart: 9217\n\tpeerEnd: 10240\n",
        "<PFUbiquitySQLCorePeerRange: 0x195949b0>\n\towningPeerID: mobile~72C62237-FE38-4B5C-8B60-557E41D79CA0\n\tentityName: FavoritedChannel\n\trangeStart: 15361\n\trangeEnd: 16384\n\tpeerStart: 9217\n\tpeerEnd: 10240\n",
        "<PFUbiquitySQLCorePeerRange: 0x19595320>\n\towningPeerID: mobile~72C62237-FE38-4B5C-8B60-557E41D79CA0\n\tentityName: FavoritedChannel\n\trangeStart: 16385\n\trangeEnd: 17408\n\tpeerStart: 9217\n\tpeerEnd: 10240\n",
        "<PFUbiquitySQLCorePeerRange: 0x19595cc0>\n\towningPeerID: mobile~72C62237-FE38-4B5C-8B60-557E41D79CA0\n\tentityName: FavoritedChannel\n\trangeStart: 17409\n\trangeEnd: 18432\n\tpeerStart: 9217\n\tpeerEnd: 10240\n"
    );
}
```

Comment: You're right, this **is** an internal iCloud exception that you can't catch. This is probably using one of your tech support incidents about, because there's nothing in the API to catch or handle this.

Comment: Thanks for the conformation Tom!

Comment: Did you ever get a solution to this fault?

Comment: No , I actually ditched Core Data all together for this app.